# Goroutines stuck after execution

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I want to have the limited number of goroutines that make some computation (func worker(), it makes some computation and places the result in a channel). Also a have another channel, that has "jobs" for my workers. As a result I can see that all jobs were computed correctly, but after computation executions stucks.

```
package main
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strings"
    "time"
)


func worker(id int, urls <- chan string, results chan<- int) {
    var data string
    for url := range urls {
        fmt.Println("worker", id, "started  job", url)
        if (strings.HasPrefix(url, "http") ||  strings.HasPrefix(url, "https")) {
            resp, err := http.Get(url)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            defer  resp.Body.Close()
            body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            data = string(body)
        } else {
            body, err := ioutil.ReadFile(url)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            data = string(body)
        }
        number := strings.Count(data, "Go")
        fmt.Println("worker", id, "finished  job", url, "Number of Go is", number)
        results <- number
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    final_result := 0
    maxNbConcurrentGoroutines := 5
    numJobs := 0
    urls := make(chan string)
    results := make(chan int)

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    start := time.Now()
    for w := 1; w <= maxNbConcurrentGoroutines; w++ {
        go worker(w, urls, results)
    }
    for scanner.Scan() {
        url := (scanner.Text())
        urls <- url
        numJobs += 1
    }
    close(urls)
    for num := range results {
        final_result += num
    }
    t := time.Now()
    elapsed := t.Sub(start)
    for i := 1; i <= numJobs; i++ {
        one_result := <- results
        final_result += one_result
    }
    fmt.Println("Number = ", final_result)
    fmt.Println("Time = ", elapsed)
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "error:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

I tried to use https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools to extract all the values from results channel, but was not succeed. What should I do to have it unstacked and gone further. Here is an example of how to run it:

```
echo -e 'https://golang.org\n/etc/passwd\nhttps://golang.org\nhttps://golang.org' | go run 1.go
```

Comment: Unrelated, you're not handling errors so this will panic when encountering any.

Comment: @JimB, could yo please clarify, I didn't get it

Comment: Printing the error and continuing as if nothing happened is not handling the error. Pass an invalid url into your program and see what happens.

Comment: @JimB, yes, I see, thanks a lot. But my main problem is in stacked state. Now it stacks if the number of jobs is greater than the number of workers. As I can see it reproduces  https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools but doesn't work correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program doesn't return because it waits the closed status of results channel.

In https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools the loop for getting results is different:

```
for a := 1; a <= numJobs; a++ {
    <-results
}
```

If you want to use `for num := range results` you need `close(results)` and determine when to call it.

You can view another example using WaitGroup at https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups

Comment: oh, I see, thanks a lot. I found the problem. It was in redundant piece of code "for num := range results {
        final_result += num
    }"

Comment: but it stucks if the number of jobs is greater than the number of workers. How to deal with it?

Comment: You can use buffered channel for urls `urls := make(chan string, maxNbConcurrentGoroutines)` or use another channel + goroutine for parsing your input

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll try it. But in theory it is not very clear for me (why I can not use simple channel)

Comment: As you can see in the doc https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2 by default, sends an receives block until the other side is ready. Buffered channel blocks only when the buffer is full.

Comment: yes, and also as I can see, I have to use some construction to wait until all goroutines finish their work, before go further in main  goroutine. Your answer above will be suitable with another channel which aggregates the "done" statuses of goroutines. Or I have to use WaitGroup